# Python parse email address with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm a beginner on regex of python

target `test.php` code:

```
<html>
  <head></head> 
  <body>
    <a href="www.google.com">josn2051@yahoo.com.tw</a>
    <div>john@yahoo.com.tw</div>
    testtest321@gmail.com
    chorm3636@test.test.test.com
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my code:

```
import requests,re

email_pattern = re.compile('([\w\-\.]+@(\w[\w\-]+\.)+[\w\-]+)')

res = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1/test.php")

a = email_pattern.findall(res.text)

print a
```

The result :

> [(u'josn2051@yahoo.com.tw', u'com.'), (u'john@yahoo.com.tw', u'com.'),
>   (u'asdfFGw@gmail.com', u'gmail.'), (u'chorm3636@test.test.test.com',
>   u'test.')]

But I want the result like:

> [josn2051@yahoo.com.us,  john@yahoo.com.us, testtest321@gmail.com, chorm3636@test.test.test.com]

What wrong in my pattern or code ?

Why the result is multiple list containse extra `com` , `gmail` , `test` ?

Thank you solve my doubts !

Comment: Because of capturing group, use `'([\w\-\.]+@(?:\w[\w\-]+\.)+[\w\-]+)'`

Comment: See http://emailregex.com and http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: So my pattern seem like  have Unnecessary Parentheses ?

Comment: Peter Wood , Thanks ! Link is very useful

Comment: [Highly relevant](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the inner group [*non-capturing*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups):

```
([\w\-\.]+@(?:\w[\w\-]+\.)+[\w\-]+)
            ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

First rule is that you do never use regexp to parse HTML, it is impossible to do it right!

Once you have a block of text that you want to validate as being and email address, you google and find 2-5 very good regexps on StackOverlfow. RegExps are not python specific.

3rd, you look for a better job, trying to scrap email addresses from websites is not an easy task and everyone here hate those that are spamming us.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, If I need to know how to defense spamming bot, Learning how to parse is one of way to learn defense.

Attack and defense always two sides to one coin.